# Jquery slider - stop sliding right

Tags: jquery, html, slider

I have made a carousel slider with jquery, where I have some products. I want the slider to stop sliding when I reach the last product, what I was able to do so far is to stop the sliding when the last product is not visible, but thats not what I need. It should stop when the last product is visible, How can I achieve that?

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/3zcn19ms/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="controls">
    <div class="control-left">left</div>
    <div class="control-right">right</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="sliderHolder">
        <div class="productsWrapper">
            <article>
                <img src="http://www.sha.org/bottle/missionbottle.jpg">
            </article>
            <article>
                <img src="http://www.sha.org/bottle/missionbottle.jpg">
            </article>
            <article>
                <img src="http://www.sha.org/bottle/missionbottle.jpg">
            </article>
            <article>
                <img src="http://www.sha.org/bottle/missionbottle.jpg">
            </article>
            <article>
                <img src="http://www.sha.org/bottle/missionbottle.jpg">
            </article>
            <article>
                <img src="http://www.sha.org/bottle/missionbottle.jpg">
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
var container = $(".sliderHolder");
var containerProducts = $(".productsWrapper").width();

var animating = false;

$(document).on("click", ".control-right", function () {
    if (parseInt(container.css("right"), 10) <= containerProducts) {
        animating = true;
        container.stop().animate({
            'right': "+=401px"
        }, 600, function () {
            animating = false;
        });
    }
});


$(document).on("click", ".control-left", function () {debugger;
    if (parseInt(container.css("right"), 10) > 0) {

        animating = true;
        container.stop().animate({
            'right': "-=401px"
        }, 600, function () {
            animating = false;
        });

    }

});

$(".control-left, .control-right").click(function () {
    if (animating) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.controls {
    top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position:relative;
}
.control-left {
    left:0;
}
.control-right {
    right:0;
}
.control-left, .control-right {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
}
.container {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.productsWrapper {
    display: inline-block;

}
.sliderHolder {
    position:relative;
    width: 28000px;
    right: 0px;
}
img {
    width: 200px;
}
article {
    width: 200px !important;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your articles are always 200px, and you slide it 2 articles at the time, your `if`-statement should be  `if (parseInt(container.css("right"), 10) <= (containerProducts - 400))` 
This way, it checks if two more would fit. If not, it will not animate.

You should try to make it a bit more dynamic, though. But this answers your question.

(fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3zcn19ms/5/)

---

### EDIT:

Hey, because of the comment you gave below this answer, I changed the code a bit. See if this helps you out:

https://jsfiddle.net/3zcn19ms/22/

Now using the size of the first image (this is only correct if all pictures have the exact same width) and the amount of articles in your wrapper.

Comment: well yes, it works that way. Actually I had already came accross that solution. But the problem is that I can still move the slider untill it only shows 2 products. What I would like it to do was, if the last product was visible it wouldnt move anymore

Comment: In my real slider, I have 5 products showing at a time, so it gets a little bit trickier also lol.

Comment: hey, thanks a lot for your help. It works great, I can have better control over the slider that way and it does what I want. Cheers ;)